# Gmail labels colour changing via javascript or gmail api in web UI

Tags: javascript, gmail, gmail-api

Is there any way to change the gmail label colors ?

I replicated the gmail call by passing the same parameters which causes colour to change ,but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way if I could do it by gmail api ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the color of labels in the Gmail UI with the Gmail API.

The only things you can change with a [modify request](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/update#try-it) is `labelListVisibility`, `messageListVisibility` and `name`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Browser Extension and modify the DOM.

Similar approach is used with https://www.inboxsdk.com/